# How to set a default sorting in a react table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am trying to make a default sorting in for all columns in `react-table v7` and show only ascending and descending, I've tried the following

```
useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: {
        sortBy: [
          columns.map((one) => {
            return {
              id: one.accessor ? one.accessor : one.id,
              desc: true,
            };
          }),
        ],
)
```

This does change order by default in table, but sorting icons don't appear on columns which I wrote like this

```
                 {column.isSorted ? (
                        column.isSortedDesc ? (
                          <ExpandLessIcon
                            fontSize="large"
                            style={{
                              transition: "250ms transform",
                              marginLeft: "7px",
                              fontSize: "20px",
                            }}
                            color="disabled"
                          ></ExpandLessIcon>
                        ) : (
                          <ExpandMoreIcon
                            fontSize="large"
                            style={{
                              transition: "250ms transform",
                              marginLeft: "7px",
                              fontSize: "20px",
                            }}
                            color="disabled"
                          ></ExpandMoreIcon>
                        )
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
```

and `column.isSorted` is still `false` when I console log.
Can someone help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.map `returns` a new array which makes `sortBy` array to have another array and it's causing issue. This works

```
        sortBy: columns.map((one) => {
          return {
            desc: false,
            id: one.accessor ? one.accessor : "",
          };
        }),
```

Comment: Hi, I am stuck with one issue in React which is related to sorting of rows in React-Table. Can you give me some idea how can I sort elements in this case - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68359658/1649217